# Building a Tree using LinedBinarTree implementation

Tags: java

can someone review my code for me.

Here is my algorithm:

initialize dataQueue with all elements to be added into the nodes in order

initialize parentQueue as empty queue

create the tree's root node with the first element of the data queue

enqueue the root node on parentQueue

while dataQueue has elements

a = dequeue from dataQueue

b = dequeue from dataQueue

parent = dequeue from parentQueue

if a is not null, add node with a as left child of parent and enqueue on parentQueue

if b is not null, add node with b as right child of parent and enqueue on parentQueue

return LinkedBinaryTree object with the root node from above

and this is how I implemented it:

```
public class TreeBuilder<T> {
    
    public LinkedBinaryTree<T> buildTree (T[] array) {
        LinkedQueue<T>  dataQueue = new LinkedQueue<T>();
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            dataQueue.enqueue(array[i]);
        }
        LinkedQueue<T> parentQueue = new LinkedQueue<T>();
        
        LinkedBinaryTree<T> root = new LinkedBinaryTree<T> (dataQueue.first());
        parentQueue.enqueue((T) root);
        
        while (!dataQueue.isEmpty()) {
            BinaryTreeNode<T> a = new BinaryTreeNode(dataQueue.dequeue());
            BinaryTreeNode<T> b = new BinaryTreeNode(dataQueue.dequeue());
            BinaryTreeNode<T> parent = new BinaryTreeNode(parentQueue.dequeue());
            if (a != null) {
                (parent).setLeft(a);
                parentQueue.enqueue((T) a);
            }
            if (b != null) {
                (parent).setRight(b);
                parentQueue.enqueue((T) b);
            }
        }
        return root;
    }


}
```

I am unsure if my implementation works efficiently because I have done a lot of casting

here is my linked binary tree class:

```
import java.util.Iterator;

public class LinkedBinaryTree<T> implements BinaryTreeADT<T> {
    private BinaryTreeNode<T> root; 

    public LinkedBinaryTree() {
        root = null;
    }

    public LinkedBinaryTree(BinaryTreeNode<T> root) {
        this.root = root;
    }

    public LinkedBinaryTree (T dataItem) {
        root = new BinaryTreeNode<T> (dataItem);
    }

    public LinkedBinaryTree (T dataItem, LinkedBinaryTree<T> leftSubtree,
            LinkedBinaryTree<T> rightSubtree) {
        root = new BinaryTreeNode<T> (dataItem);
        if (leftSubtree != null) root.setLeft(leftSubtree.root);
        else root.setLeft(null);

        if (rightSubtree !=null) root.setRight(rightSubtree.root);
        else root.setRight(null);
    }   

    public BinaryTreeNode<T> getRoot() {
        return root;
    }   

    public T getDataRoot() throws EmptyCollectionException {
        if (isEmpty()) {
            throw new EmptyCollectionException("Empty tree");
        }
        return root.getData();
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return root == null;
    }

    public int size (BinaryTreeNode<T> r) {
        if (r == null) {
            return 0;
        }

        int tmp = 1;

        if (r.getLeft() != null) {
            tmp += size(r.getLeft());
        }
        if (r.getRight() != null) {
            tmp += size(r.getRight());
        }

        return tmp;
    }

    public boolean contains (BinaryTreeNode<T> r, T targetElement) {
        if (r == null) {
            return false;
        }

        if (r.getData().equals(targetElement)) {
            return true;
        } else {

            if (r.getLeft() != null) {
                boolean tmp = contains(r.getLeft(), targetElement);
                if (tmp) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            if (r.getRight() != null) {
                boolean tmp = contains(r.getRight(), targetElement);
                if (tmp) {
                    return true;
                }
            }

        }

        return false;
    }

    public Iterator<T> iteratorInOrder() {
        ArrayUnorderedList<T> tempList = new ArrayUnorderedList<T>();
        inorder (root, tempList);

        return tempList.iterator();
    }

    protected void inorder (BinaryTreeNode<T> node, ArrayUnorderedList<T> tempList) {
        if (node != null) {
            inorder (node.getLeft(), tempList);
            tempList.addToRear(node.getData());
            inorder (node.getRight(), tempList);
        }
    }

    public Iterator<T> iteratorPreOrder() {
        ArrayUnorderedList<T> tempList = new ArrayUnorderedList<T>();
        preorder(root, tempList);

        return tempList.iterator();
    }

    protected void preorder (BinaryTreeNode<T> node, ArrayUnorderedList<T> tempList) {
        if (node != null) {
            tempList.addToRear(node.getData());
            preorder(node.getLeft(), tempList);
            preorder(node.getRight(), tempList);
        }
    }

    public Iterator<T> iteratorPostOrder() {
        ArrayUnorderedList<T> tempList = new ArrayUnorderedList<T>();
        postorder(root, tempList);

        return tempList.iterator();
    }

    protected void postorder (BinaryTreeNode<T> node, ArrayUnorderedList<T> tempList) {
        if (node != null) {
            postorder(node.getLeft(), tempList);
            postorder(node.getRight(), tempList);
            tempList.addToRear(node.getData());
        }
    }

    public Iterator<T> iteratorLevelOrder() {
        ArrayUnorderedList<T> tempList = new ArrayUnorderedList<T>();
        LinkedQueue<BinaryTreeNode<T>> queue = new LinkedQueue<BinaryTreeNode<T>>();
        BinaryTreeNode<T> node = null;

        queue.enqueue(root);

        while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
            node = queue.dequeue();
            tempList.addToRear(node.getData());
            // Add left child.
            if (node.getLeft() != null) {
                queue.enqueue(node.getLeft());
            }
            // Add right child.
            if (node.getRight() != null) {
                queue.enqueue(node.getRight());
            }
        }

        return tempList.iterator();
    }
    
}
```